# how to resolve UnicodeEncodeError while converting to str

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

this is my code

```
import requests as re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = re.get("https://skidlamer.github.io/js/Skidfest.user.js")
soup = bs(r.text,"lxml")

with open("script.txt","w") as file:
    file.write(soup)
```

and this is the error im getting

```
File "C:\Users\Anonymouse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4a9' in position 38190: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You sure this error comes from the code above? The code fails early on `file.write(soup)`.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to write to file? The html? You want to open the file in binary mode. Try `with open("script.txt","wb") as file:`

Comment: Whene i run the above code in ubuntu its show `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not BeautifulSoup`. after convert soup object to str. Its work.

Answer (score 0):

i added .encode("utf-8") after converting the beautiful soup object to str type and it worked